# Internet drops when I download

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I recently bought an [ASUS VivoBook V301LP-DS51T](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JB3N6KS) and am having internet problems. It runs fine as long as I don't download anything. As soon as I do, the speed drops really quick until I am disconnected.

I unchecked the box that allows the computer to turn off the wireless adapter in device manager. I also put my power options to max performance, but it still happens. My network adapter is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG.

Specs

```
Windows 8.1
Modem: Arris TM822
Router: Just says Optimum
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried limiting the download speed? Also what Windows version and wireless router do you have? Some routers don't split the Internet bandwidth fair enough so that each application gets a share of it.

Comment: Arris TM822 is the modem. The router is something from Optimum and it doesn't say the model or anything on there; just says optimum. I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Please put that information into the question and also add the **windows-8.1** tag.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with you download with another device connected to the same router?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as some people have commented limiting download speeds definitely works, but it will decrease your download speed dramatically and really isn't worth the wait.

My suggestion is that you (ironically) download a program that downloads your file through a program even faster that it already does. It won't slow down your computer at all.

Please upvote if all goes well. If you would like an example of in my opinion the best download manger, here it is.
SpeedBit: www.speedbit.com/